# How to set cursor position at end of text while open notepad (log file)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my application, i add/append exception log in notepad and now logs are too big so to make it user friendly i decide to set cursor position at end of text of log file so when user click on "View Log" button from application s/he can show most recent log. So to avoid scrolling i want to set cursor at last.

Currently i am simply using : `Process.Start("notepad.exe",Path)` to open log file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once Notepad is started, find its window. You can use [`user32.dll.FindWindow`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/csharpgeneral/thread/c9ae6163-b31a-407f-88ba-e290a14a60ee).
2. Use `SendMessage` to send [WM_VSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787577%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `SB_BOTTOM` parameter to this window.