# Open file with specific cursor location

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write a program that can search a word in a .txt file and open that file with the cursor at the specific location where the word was found (In front of the word). I've already implemented the searching and I know how to open a file, but I can't seem to find a way to open the file with the cursor at a specific position. Is there a way to do such a thing? Thanks :)

Edit : Just to clarify, when I say 'Open', I mean literally opening the file with Notepad, not opening the file with a Streamreader.

Edit 2 : I can't assume Notepad is the default text editor, but if needs be, I can force the file to be opened with it.

Comment: You could send the Arrow Right key x times to the window. But there may be better solutions.
Not exactly the same, but could be a clue to find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034800/how-to-set-cursor-position-at-end-of-text-while-open-notepad-log-file

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with notepad, but you could do it with notepad++ using the following command line arguments

```
-n: Scroll to indicated line (LineNumber) on filepath.
-c: Scroll to indicated column (ColumnNumber) on filepath.
-p: Scroll to indicated 0 base position (Position) on filepath.
```

Comment: Sadly, I can't do this because I cannot guarantee everyone who's gonna use my program has notepad++ installed or configured as default program for txt files. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TextBox1.Focus(); // So the caret shows up
            string word = "hello";
            TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
            var i = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word);
            if (i != -1) TextBox1.CaretIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

This will place the caret in front of the first occurance of the word 'hello'. You can even highlight the text by using TextBox1.Select(int offset, int length).